# (GeometryTypeError: Unknown geometry type: featurecollection) How to extend a function to all values in a column dependent on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, coordinates, geopandas

I have written a function to check if a point is within a polygon, and if it is to return "True,{branch_name}" where branch_name is the name of the polygon, and when trying to extend this function to the whole column, I keep encountering the "**GeometryTypeError**: Unknown geometry type: featurecollection" error.

The function I have written is:

```
def latlon_check(intsct, area, branch): #intsct = point, area = polygon, branch= branch name
    check = intsct.within(shape(area))
    if check == True:
        within.append(f"True,{branch}")
    else:
        within.append(f"False")
    return within
```

intsct is in df1 - a dataframe with a few hundred rows in it

area and branch are in df2 - a data frame with 10 rows

**Note: The function works fine when inputting single values as arguments.**

I want to make a new column in df1 where every row will either say "False" or "True,{branch_name}" showing which branch the point is in.

Using:

```
df1['within'] = df1['intsct'].apply(latlon_check, args = (df2['area'],df2['branch']))
```

and get the error:

```
GeometryTypeError: Unknown geometry type: featurecollection
```

I have tried rewriting the column as a string then converting it back to 'geometry' and still had the same error, will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points

- have used **geopandas** sample geometry to simulate data you describe. Making columns of two data frames consistent with what your describe
- your sample code uses a function `shape()` it's not clear what this is.  Possibly takes a WKT string and converts it into a polygon.  Have removed as a polygon is being passed in context I have simulated
- **core** you are passing series from `df2` by the way you are calling `apply()`.  Hence have refactored `latlon_check()` to use series rather than singletons.
- `within.append()` this is function to add items to a **list** there is no **list**.  Have just simplified to `return` the desired string

### MWE

```
import geopandas as gpd

# simulate data that matches question
df1 = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
df2 = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
df1 = df1.rename(columns={"geometry":"intsct"})
df2 = df2.sample(10, random_state=42).rename(columns={"geometry":"area","name":"branch"}).loc[:,["branch","area"]]

def latlon_check(intsct, area, branch): #intsct = point, area = polygon series, branch= branch name series
    for i, area_ in area.items():
        if intsct.within(area_):
            return f"True,{branch.loc[i]}"
    return "False"
df1["within"] = df1['intsct'].apply(latlon_check, args = (df2['area'],df2['branch']))
```

### sample output

|  | name | intsct | within |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vatican City | POINT (12.4533865 41.9032822) | False |
| 1 | San Marino | POINT (12.4417702 43.9360958) | False |
| 2 | Vaduz | POINT (9.5166695 47.1337238) | False |
| 3 | Lobamba | POINT (31.1999971 -26.4666675) | False |
| 4 | Luxembourg | POINT (6.1300028 49.6116604) | False |
| 22 | Podgorica | POINT (19.2663069 42.4659725) | True,Montenegro |
| 57 | Port-au-Prince | POINT (-72.3379804 18.5429705) | True,Haiti |
| 84 | Riga | POINT (24.0999654 56.9500238) | True,Latvia |
| 114 | Sucre | POINT (-65.2595156 -19.0409708) | True,Bolivia |
| 119 | Yerevan | POINT (44.5116055 40.1830966) | True,Armenia |
| 122 | La Paz | POINT (-68.151931 -16.4960278) | True,Bolivia |
| 198 | Ürümqi | POINT (87.5730598 43.8069581) | True,China |
| 199 | Chengdu | POINT (104.0680736 30.6719459) | True,China |
| 214 | Taipei | POINT (121.5683333 25.0358333) | True,Taiwan |
| 227 | Beijing | POINT (116.39420089260611 39.901720309862675) | True,China |
| 232 | Shanghai | POINT (121.4345588 31.2183983) | True,China |
| 242 | Hong Kong | POINT (114.1830635 22.3069268) | True,China |

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. 
I'm quite new, so could you explain how does the line: <for i, area_ in area.items():> work?
<for i in> would iterate through the items in the series, but what happens when you have two variables like that?

Comment: I'm using this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html. I want the index as well as the value to use to use to get the appropriate `branch` when a polygon is found